# Vmware Horizont Client 4.0.2 64bit Ubuntu 16.04.1 - No home sharing

Tags: 16.04, vmware

Using Ubuntu 16.04.1 64bit and Vmware Horizont Client 4.0.2 I can set Sharing home folder, but when I try to save/open a local file, I don't see my local file system. It used to work with U14.04.
Any hints?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a known bug:
[according to this thread on vmware communities](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/545103?start=0&tstart=0)

> We still doesn't officially support 16.04 in our Matrix. And it's a known issue which is tracked internally.

and

> Thanks for using Horizon product but this is not the right place to talk about product future plan. Please engage with the sales rep of VMware for your company. Thanks.

I have not found any workaround.